# SR0029 - what is it, and where does it come from?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I am currently struggeling with an error in Visual Studio 2010, where it says:

```
SR0029: The method/constructor 'HandleThisParticularEvent' has 8 parameters. A maximum of 7 is allowed.
```

I cannot either find any hints to solve this issue (not connected with database-query-issues), nor what this error describes in general. Where does it come from, and why is it thrown on different occasions?

Edit: I already tried [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c4b5053-996f-4854-bf57-235ed41c6cca/suppressing-sr-warnings?forum=vstsdb) but a right-click on the warning does not show any option to suppress the warning.

Comment: Well, that sounds like it's from something like FxCop (not necessarily that exactly, but some kind of style checker). It's not from the C# compiler itself. The meaning seems pretty self-explanatory though... *if* you decide to fix it (I'd expect this to be a warning rather than an error), using a smaller number of parameters, each of which includes multiple related values, is the way forward...

Comment: I already did some research on "maybe it's style- or fxcop", but it seems it's not any of these. Afaik, stylecop rules start with SAxxxx and fxcop rules have CA at the beginning.
I am going to fix this issue anyway, but I really want to know where this is coming from - and why there is no proper documentation about such issues.

Comment: Well it's *something* like that. You're in a far better situation to see what plugins you've got installed etc than we are... (Do you get the same warning when building directly with msbuild? Have you looked closely at the csproj file?)

Comment: seach whole word “HandleThisParticularEvent” insolution

Comment: You can have custom rules in most style checkers which wouldn't necessarily start with the standard prefixes. Also any style/fx/ca rule numbers I'd expect an in instant result on google.